# For the given multiple nodes find a node

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Without reading all the given User nodes, is there a way to find it by using the given Exam nodes?

Example:

[image]

For the given Exam nodes `mtech` and `mca`, how would I find the User node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDITED:
For a given two Exam nodes, you can find the enrolled User node on both Exams (mtech and mca) by doing 1) an undirected match to User node 2) collect the exam names 3) then check if both names mtech and mca are in the collection

```
 MATCH (u :User) - [ :enrolled] - (e :Exam)
 WHERE e.name in [ 'mtech', 'mca' ]   // assuming that an index is created for Exam.name
 WITH collect(distinct e.name) as exams, u
 WHERE ALL(ex in [ 'mtech', 'mca' ] where ex in exams )
 RETURN u
```

Comment: This return users which are enrolled in either 'mtech' or 'mca'. I want users which are enrolled into both exams.
Furthermore, I strongly believe the Match will search through all the given Users in the database.

Comment: I edited my answer @KaranDhir.  You need to collect the Exam names and check that ALL names are mtech and mca.

Comment: Marking it correct. But I think it could be further optimised if we start Match by specifying the Exam name and also putting "Constraint Unique" on the Exam name.

Comment: Yes, you can also do that.